# What to do with the question where the OP is constant vandalizing the question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

This question [ISBN accept numbers only (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21497798/1309352) is constantly editing the content of the question which is vandalizing and making the question null and void (and the answers too).

And because of these edits it's constantly making into the low-quality review queue.

What to do about it? Flag?

Comment: Flag. That's it.